# Meteorjs with Mongodb tls/ssl connection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need to use existing replicaset mongodb database which is encrypted with [tls/ssl](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/) connections, with Meteorjs. I can connect Meteorjs with mongodb without ssl. How can I add tls/ssl to this connection ?

Comment: have you tried this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Syntax**

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

**Connection Options**

> **uri.ssl**
>
> true: Initiate the connection with TLS/SSL.
>
> false: Initiate the connection without TLS/SSL.
>
> The default value is false

[source](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-options)

**Example:**

```
mongodb://username:password@192.168.0.5:28017/database?ssl=true
```

Comment: How do you add the certificates and pem files to it ?

Comment: no need to include pem file.  edit `bind_ip = 0.0.0.0` in  `/etc/mongodb.conf`

Comment: then restart mongodb `/etc/init.d/mongodb restart`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ssl=true at the end 
mongodb://localhost:27017/test?ssl=true
[Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/) is all You want on client side